# What to use - 'I' or 'Me'?

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Which is correct, “you and I” or “you and me”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/which-is-correct-you-and-i-or-you-and-me)
>   [When do I use “I” instead of “me?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313/when-do-i-use-i-instead-of-me)

Which one of the following sentences is correct?

> John and me are working on it.

or

> John and I are working on it.

Comment: aaah.. I tried searching with 'I' 'me' but didnt get to this..

Comment: Yeah, the Stack Exchange search doesn't work for short common words. Google might work better in such cases.