# "You and I" versus "you and me"

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, conjunctions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is correct, “you and I” or “you and me”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/which-is-correct-you-and-i-or-you-and-me)

When I was in primary school, I was advised by my English teacher to use "you and I" instead of "you and me." I know some people out there still use "You and me." Can anyone explain why we should use "you and I" and what is wrong with "you and me"?