# When do I use "me" and when "I"?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, conjunctions, personal-pronouns, objects

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I put myself last?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/should-i-put-myself-last)

I get this mixed up so often. Should I say:

> Me and Rob are going swimming.

or

> I and Rob are going swimming.

I know the latter sounds REALLY awkward and I'd probably never say it that way but

> Rob and I are going swimming.

sound perfectly fine (confusing because *Rob* and *I* aren't grammatically different here).

In the original sentence both *I* and *Rob* are the subject, so why use the accusative *me*?

Also why do we say:

> She and Rob are going swimming.

but not:

> I and Rob are going swimming.

?

Comment: See [When do I use “I” instead of “me?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313/) and [Which is correct, “you and I” or “you and me”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/)