# Which is correct: "you and I" or "you and me"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, pronouns, objects, subjects

I was told the correct usage is for example:

"My wife and me" but I hear often "I and my wife" or "my wife and I".

Google gives 34M results for "My wife and I" and 909K results for "My wife and me"
Which is the correct form and why?

It occurred to me that maybe it could depend on the rest of the phrase? (subject or object)

> "My wife and I are eating an apple"
>
> "You can see my wife and me in this
> picture"

Comment: You might want to look at: [Which is correct, “you and I” or “you and me”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/which-is-correct-you-and-i-or-you-and-me)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're right that it depends on the rest of the phrase (subject or object):

- "My wife and I are eating an apple" is correct because "my wife and I" is the **subject** of the sentence. You could replace "my wife and I" with "we".
- "You can see my wife and me in this picture" is correct because "my wife and me" is the **object** of the sentence. You could replace "my wife and me" with "us".

You can often check this quickly by removing the other person from the sentence and see if it makes sense. For example:

Subject:

- "**You and I like apples**". Removing "you and" gives "**I like apples**", which is **correct**.
- "**You and me like apples**". Removing "you and" gives "**me like apples**", which is **incorrect**.

Object:

- "**John gave the apple to you and me**". Removing "you and" gives "**John gave the apple to me**", which is **correct**.
- "**John gave the apple to you and I**". Removing "you and" gives "**John gave the apple to I**", which is **incorrect**.

Comment: I have never known such an easy way to think about it!

Comment: There's another variation "<somebody> and myself" for when the subject is "I" and the phrase occurs as the object. For example, "During tax season, I tend to drive my wife and myself crazy". Note: In common usage, "and myself" is often used incorrectly when "and I" or "and me" should be used instead.

Comment: +100 This simple mistake makes me cringe whenever I hear it in popular music. I do realize that pop is not exactly the epitome of proper expression, but for some reason this always stands out to me.

Comment: Nothing in common usage is ever used incorrectly.