# Thank You for inviting Steve and {me/I}?

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions, personal-pronouns, grammatical-case, coordinating-conjunctions

When writing a thank you note from a husband and wife, is it correct to write the note as...

> "Thank you for inviting Steve and me to your home for the birthday celebration."

Or is it,

> "Thank you for inviting Steve and I"?

This seems so simple but yet I get stumped every time :/

Comment: Would you write "Thank you for inviting I ..."?

Comment: Related: [Is 'my wife and I' correct English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/156369/is-my-wife-and-i-correct-english); [“Me and my wife” or “my wife and me”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48397/me-and-my-wife-or-my-wife-and-me) and [When do I use “I” instead of “me?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313/when-do-i-use-i-instead-of-me)

Comment: Also related: [Which is correct: “you and I” or “you and me”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7188/which-is-correct-you-and-i-or-you-and-me) and [“I and someone”, “me and someone” or “I and someone we”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59618/i-and-someone-me-and-someone-or-i-and-someone-we?lq=1)

Answer (score 5):

Two converging confusions seem to beset you:

1. *[Gerunds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund)* are confusing because they behave like nouns and verbs. They can take an object like a verb, but they fill a place in the sentence like a noun:

> A gerund behaves as a verb within a clause (so that it may be modified
>   by an adverb or have an object); but the resulting clause as a whole
>   (sometimes consisting of only one word, the gerund itself) functions
>   as a noun within the larger sentence.

In the sentence, the phrase: *inviting Steve and me to your home for the birthday celebration*, is the object of the preposition *for*.

*Inviting* is the gerund verb of the phrase, while *Steve and me* is the object of the gerund.

2. The real issue is the compound object of the verb: *Me* is the correct expression for the direct object, and this simple test confirms its correctness, when you eliminate the first object:

> *Thank you for inviting me to your home for the birthday celebration.*

Adding Steve again:

> *Thank you for inviting Steve and me to your home for the birthday celebration.*

---

en.wikipedia.org