# Is there a difference between using me and I in those sentences?

Tags: grammar

(1) Annie and me went to the theater 
(2) Annie and I went to the theater

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is correct, "you and I" or "you and me"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/which-is-correct-you-and-i-or-you-and-me) Or [Which is correct: "you and I" or "you and me"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7188/which-is-correct-you-and-i-or-you-and-me)

Answer (score 1):

In general, try looking at the sentence without the “You and” or “*So-and-so* and” - in this case, try omitting “Annie and”, and see which one is correct in that case. That will give you the correct answer for the sentence *with* the “*So-and-so* and”.

Using your sentence as an example, ***<s>Annie and</s> I went to the theater*** would be correct, therefore ***Annie and I went to the theater*** is also correct.

Look at the both of the questions that were indicated as possible duplicates in the comments; they are in fact duplicates, and will answer your question.

Comment: Then why are you supplying yet another answer to the many more that already exist at the questions that this one duplicates?

Comment: And -1 for an incorrect answer, and if you read amongst the other answers you'll find out why. Namely native English speakers do not use *coupled noun phrases* in a way that your proffered advice  describes.

Comment: @Clare - The advice I gave was the advice I was given back in grade school, and it has always worked for me. Where it _appeared_ to be incorrect, it was because the ostensible "correct" answer has always turned out to be "hypercorrection", or misapplying a rule to a case where it does not apply.

Comment: @Clare - 1047 supports my answer. So does 313. So does 7188. How is my answer wrong?

Comment: @Clare: Noting that the idiomatic usage [*You and me both!*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22you+and+me+both+he%22) (expressing shared experience or thinking) always occurs in that order, whereas with [*Me and Sue went (somewhere)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22me+and+Sue+went%22) we nearly always put ***me*** first, I think Jeff's perspective here is relevant.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - And *Me and Sue/you/him went ...* is very definitely incorrect, even if commonly (mis)used.

Comment: Jeff: - Well, let's be clear here. I totally reject the idea that constructions such as *Me and you have known each other a long time* are somehow "incorrect". Grammarians have been telling people that for centuries (probably based on some syntactic constraint in *Latin*), but native speakers have largely ignored their teachers once they're out of school. The point I was trying to make is no-one *ever* uses the "compound subject" form ***I** and you are mates* - but (depending on the verb, I think) *me and you* is in some contexts more common than *you and me* (which *may* mean something).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - they may not use "I and you" or "I and Joe", but "Joe and I" or "You and I" are quite definitely used. Yes, the rules are because historically, the grammarians tried to impose the rules of Latin onto English, but they are not as widely ignored as you seem to think - there is a definite attitude that "You and me are friends" is lower-class than "You and I are friends" in speech, and in writing, the former is generally regarded as outright 'sub-literate', and provokes outrage if done by a teacher.

Comment: I certainly accept that many people (still?) think *You and me are friends* is "lower-class". And obviously at least *some* people for whom that's the "natural" form will be tempted to switch to *You and **I*** in contexts where they want to avoid being thus stigmatised. But what intrigues me about usage in this area is that whereas ***A + B*** and ***B + A*** are equivalent in mathematics, although ***I and you*** is *syntactically* as valid as ***You and I***, it's nowhere near equivalent in terms of idiomacy (for reasons that make little or no sense to me).