# "You and I" versus "you and me"

Tags: grammaticality, synonyms, pronouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is correct, “you and I” or “you and me”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/which-is-correct-you-and-i-or-you-and-me)

I was surprised to hear "you and I," when I expected "you and me." Are the two expressions synonyms to each other?