# In this sentence "Me and you" or "You and I " is correct?

Tags: grammar, nouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Which is correct, “you and I” or “you and me”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/which-is-correct-you-and-i-or-you-and-me)

Consider this conversation:

> "Hey, we've been seeing each other for a couple of months"
>
> "Did you really expect to get married two weeks? I am not easy like other girls."
>
> "It's not about other girls. It's about **me and you"**

Is *me and you* correct and why?

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate of the quewstion mentioned: a different point of grammar is involved.

Answer (score 1):

"It's not about you, it's about me" and "It's about you and me" are both correct, with the first *me* telling you what to say for the second *me*.

You should usually put *I* or *me* at the end of a list out of politeness.

Comment: Just as an aside, the polite "I or me" is partly responsible for the hypercorrective misuse of "I," e.g., "between you and I."