# "I and others" or "me and others"

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Which is correct, “you and I” or “you and me”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/which-is-correct-you-and-i-or-you-and-me)
>   [When do I use “I” instead of “me?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313/when-do-i-use-i-instead-of-me)

Could you please explain more in an answer, so that **I and other developers** would use benefit.

Could you please explain more in an answer, so that **me and other developers** would use benefit.

Which one is correct? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Not really that difficult and almost nothing to explain :)

"I would benefit." + "Other developers would benefit." = "I and other developers would benefit."