# Which sentence is more acceptable?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [When do I use "I" instead of "me?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313/when-do-i-use-i-instead-of-me)
>   [Which is correct, "you and I" or "you and me"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/which-is-correct-you-and-i-or-you-and-me)

Which of the following sentences is more acceptable?

> "This is just between you and I."

or

> "This is just between you and me."

I have come across both of these sentences in movies and I'm not sure which one is more acceptable. Can someone help me?