# "...as you and I am" versus "...as you and I are"

Tags: pronouns, verb-agreement, grammatical-case

Which is the correct usage to end the following sentence?

> [person] is not as [adjective] as you and I [am/are].

<sub>I'd also like to see some good fill-in-the-blanks.</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Personally, being a fan of brevity, I'd go with door number three: neither.

```
Eeyore isn't as fun as you and I.
```

In a pinch though, you'd certainly need the plural verb:

```
Winnie the Pooh isn't as tall as you and I are.
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be "Eeyore isn't as fun as (you and) me"?

Comment: @Fraser Orr: As per this long discussion here(http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/which-is-correct-you-and-i-or-you-and-me?lq=1), it certainly should be "Eeyore isn't as fun as (you and) me?" instead of 'I'.
Your comments please.

Answer (score 4):

The "and" makes "you" and "I" a group of two people, so the plural has to be used.

Answer (score 2):

*Are*, but *we are* would be much more likely.

Comment: "Joe isn't as awesome as we are" is more ambiguous and sounds less natural than "Joe isn't as awesome as you and I are"

Comment: Hey, Barrie. I've been reading your answers around this site since you joined us. I've also read the info you've got in the "about me" section. I'm glad you're a part of this community and I like everything you have to say, but your last answers I've read were too short and simple, although correct. Please, don't let it become a habit. I wouldn't like to see such an amazing person like you start posting such simple answers, especially with all the knowledge you've got!

Comment: Specifying "you and I" would be good if "we" implies more people than "you and I" does.

Comment: IMHO this is a situation where the brevity is appropriate. I do agree that some of readers of this question could do with a bit more of a "why" though.

Comment: Thank you, Rimmer, kind of you to say so. As with speeches and skirts, so with posts: there’s a fine line between what is long enough to cover the subject, and what is short enough to be interesting.