# "Someone and I" syntactic-analysis

Tags: syntactic-analysis

This is a topic I became curious about, and I'm not able to find much info online about this if any. This being the grammatical rule of "Someone and I" where you place yourself last when listing yourself and others, versus the "I and someone," which I've always been taught is incorrect, but many people have been saying it is. I've looked online for the reason why it's one or the other, but more often than not, I come across the "is it someone and I or someone and Me?" question which doesn't help and is not what I'm looking for. As I mentioned, I am curious about this grammatical anomaly; Which is correct, and what is the reasoning/rule that specifies why it is correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["I and someone", "me and someone" or "I and someone we"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59618/i-and-someone-me-and-someone-or-i-and-someone-we) Search for Barrie England's quote from ‘The Cambridge Guide to English Usage’. This concerns politeness structuring rather than grammar; it is custom- rather than syntax-related (but probably equally important).

Comment: Yes, it's not a grammatical rule. It's a rule of Western etiquette and has nothing to do with English _per se_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's still the case that the other question you linked to is about "I" vs "me", not the order.

Comment: @Barmar It certainly is, but (1) I have recently seen an endorsement from a mod saying that answers in reasonably closely related questions (rather than precise duplicates) may be cited if they provide what is essentially the definitive answer; (2) How many times does 'It's a politeness convention rather than a definite grammatical rule' have to be said on this? Have _you_ done a reasonable check for duplicates in an attempt to keep the site trim and readily searchable?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth As I mentioned in the question itself, I'm not asking for the difference between I and Me, rather the order in which this falls under.

Comment: And " 'This concerns politeness structuring rather than grammar; it is custom- rather than syntax-related (but probably equally important).' [And the custom is to place oneself last.]", all given in the duplicates, explains this.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ah, sorry I seem to have missed that part in your initial post, my apologies for that. Thank you for your help with this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When do I use "I" instead of "me?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313/when-do-i-use-i-instead-of-me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this answer your question? ["I and someone", "me and someone" or "I and someone we"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59618/i-and-someone-me-and-someone-or-i-and-someone-we?noredirect=1&lq=1) Search for Barrie England's quote from ‘The Cambridge Guide to English Usage’. This concerns politeness structuring rather than grammar; it is custom- rather than syntax-related (but probably equally important).

-[Edwin Ashworth](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/21655/edwin-ashworth)