# Jon and I or Jon and me?

Tags: grammar

How do I know when to use Jon and I, or Jon and me? I can't really figure it out. I've tried to teach myself, but I just can't seem to do it. Will someone please help me figure this problem out?

Comment: Prescriptivism dictates that if you would use I or me alone, then use that in combination. Actual use differs so substantially so that Angermeyer and Singer argue that "John and me" (for instance) is the Standard in subject position, with "John and I" as a polite standard, and "me and John" as merely vernacular.

Comment: Also relevant http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/4178979?uid=2&uid=4&sid=21104180427191

Comment: This type of question has been done to death. There are tens, dozens, scores of similar questions 1) [Which is correct: You and I or You and me?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/which-is-correct-you-and-i-or-you-and-me) 2) [Between you and (“me” or “I”)?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152566/between-you-and-me-or-i) 3) [“That was me” vs. “That was I”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143363/that-was-me-vs-that-was-i) 4) Similar or identical questions: http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+me+I

Comment: Users are urged to do a little research before asking questions. There have been excellent answers posted which would be pointless to repeat, and nigh on impossible to improve on. I am positive the listed questions will help the OP further and clarify any remaining doubts.

Comment: The correct response to a dulpicated question is to mark it as duplicate, not to downvote or make snide remarks. This doesn't create productive atmosphere or an image of a welcoming community. 

Downvoted should be used when the question itself is bad.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple test that I've never known to fail in this classic English problem:

Phrase the statement as two separate statements, one referring to Jon and the other to you.  In the one referring to you, if 'me' sounds correct, use 'Jon and me', if 'I' works, use 'Jon and I'.

A couple of examples to illustrate:

> He gave the money to Jon and (I/me).

Try it using only you:

> He gave the money to me.

As you can see, 'me' is the winner because using 'I' here would be horrid.

> Jon and (I/me) are going to see a play.

Unless you are a caveman, you wouldn't say 'Me am going to see a play', so 'I' is correct here.

Comment: "Jon and we are..." makes my ears bleed, but "We are..." is the only correct isolated form. The substitution rule isn't perfect, and arguably (quite well arguably, in fact) not all that appropriate for English grammar as we understand it today.

Comment: Why would anyone say "Jon and we.."?

Comment: If Jon is joining me and my girlfriend to go to the movies, how would you say it? "We and Jon", "Jon and we", "Us and Jon" or "Jon and us"?

Comment: It sure sounds like Jon might be joining us. Once he gets here, we will...

Comment: @ElliotFrisch, that's rewording it though. One can also avoid the Jon and I by using the same strategy. "Jon is joining me, we will..." but doesn't take the issue