# Me and Susie are going to dinner.

Tags: grammar

Is it ever correct to say "Me and Jon are going to the movies"?

Comment: No, but you can sing "Me and Julio are down by the schoolyard."

Comment: related: [Which is correct, “you and I” or “you and me”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/which-is-correct-you-and-i-or-you-and-me)

Comment: @deadrat +1, despite the fact that you got the song lyrics and grammar wrong!

Answer (score 2):

No. "Me" must either be the object, "The dragon ate me" or the complement to subject, "The dragon is me". Whenever you are the the subject, always use "I"!

> I and John are going to the movies.

and if you're being polite, you put the yourself last:

> John and I are going to the movies.