# Me, myself or I in non-I clause

Tags: grammar, pronouns, writing-style

MS Word is underlining the word *myself* and I am now wondering if I should be using *me* instead, seeing as the subject is not I. Which one is correct? Are both possible?

> 1. At this point, putting as much distance between **myself** and John as possible is the only thing that matters.
> 2. At this point, putting as much distance between **me** and John as possible is the only thing that matters.

It shouldn't be “between John and I” should it?

I have another question about whether to use I or **me** in the sentence below:

> 3. The tension is heavy **between John and I** as we find ourselves alone in the driveway...

Or should it be:

> 4. The tension is heavy **between me and John** as we find ourselves alone in the driveway...

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: It's best to ask two questions in two posts.

Comment: I would say that 1 is fine if it is clear that it is "you" who is distancing yourself from John.

Comment: The default pronoun is the non-reflexive "me", but it is possible here to 'override' the default and use reflexive "myself". But the override is optional, it's a matter of personal choice. Regarding "I" vs "me", the usual rule is that where a personal pronoun is complement to a preposition, such as "between", it should be in the accusative case, so "me" would be correct. The ordering is a matter of choice, with the pronoun appearing second of the two complements being seen perhaps as a matter of misplaced politeness.

Comment: See [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1047/2085) for the answer to the non-reflexive aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your second question is easy. "Between John and I" is one of the most common errors in English.

It's funny: you wouldn't say "The tension is heavy between we," which is equivalent to number 3.

I believe the confusion arises because of a similar-sounding problem, with a different answer. A lot of people tend to say:

```
John and me were having a problem.
```

When of course they should be saying:

```
John and I were having a problem.
```

Since the solution to this problem is to change "me" to "I," there's a tendency to repeat the solution whenever you have something that sounds similar -- because it also contains "John and me."  :)

As far as the first question: "Myself" sounds right to me, since the protagonist is "acting upon" himself or herself, so to speak.