# "Who's going to the movies?" "[Person] and I." or "[Person] and me."

Tags: expressions

This is weird.

I always heard the rule about removing the other person's name, but what's the deal in this case? "[Person] and I." would be the subject, so that seems like it is right, but I don't think I would just say "I." in response to the question.

Edit: My question was flagged as maybe a duplicate. I suppose it is different because I am asking if I were to include another person in the answer.

Comment: For a question dealing with case after the conjunction "and," see [Which is correct, “you and I” or “you and me”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1047)

Comment: The funny thing is, this just makes me have even more questions. It seems like it should be "[Person] and I." because I guess that implies "[Person] and I (are going to the movies)." 

Which just makes me wonder why most people would insist on saying "Me!" to that question and no one really says "I!" in response.

Comment: The rule in American English is that you don't use ***I*** unless it's the subject of a clause and is followed by a verb that agrees with it. This would be the subject of a clause, but it isn't followed by a verb. So _`Person` and me_ would be the normal answer. If I were making a joke, I might say _`Person` and I_; but probably not.

Comment: Thanks for the info, John Lawler. I really appreciate it. I had honestly never heard the rule of "I" needing to be followed by a verb. I only knew of the subject/object rules. That really clarifies a lot. 

Never thought I would be posting here over a Facebook comment.

Answer (score 0):

It is true you would not just answer I, because the standard answer would be "I am." (The whole answer would be "I am going to the movies," but the answer is shortened because the verb *going* and the prepositional phrase "to the movies" are assumed.) When you add another person to the answer, "[Person] and I" sounds right. The long answer would be "[Person] and I are going to the movies." You could say "I and [Person]" but it doesn't sound right since when we include other people we usually put the first person pronoun at the end (e.g. "put it in the oven for baby and me").

Comment: Hello, Daniel. This has been discussed ad nauseum on ELU. Please (1) don't give 'answers' you're not backing up with supporting references; (2) Have a look at Professor Lawler's informed answer (posted as a 'comment') above, especially his 'rule for the 2010s' (as a UK resident, I'd say that nowadays 'Bill and me' sounds more natural over here too); (3) Don't expect English to behave logically.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> The rule in American English is that you don't use ***I*** unless it's the subject of a clause and is followed by a verb that agrees with it. This would be the subject of a clause, but it isn't followed by a verb. So *`Person` and me* would be the normal answer. If I were making a joke, I might say *`Person` and I*; but probably not.