# You and I or you and me

Tags: grammar

So if I wrote:

> You and I have a lot of places to go

is this wrong?

I was chatting to a friend on social media and he kept correcting me. 'You should' and 'I should' sound correct however 'me should' sounds wrong but no matter how hard I tried to explain from my side we got nowhere .

Comment: The classic rule of thumb is that if you deleted "you and", would you write "I" or "me"?  So "You and I have places to go" but "She spoke to you and me".  Alternatively, use "we" and "us" instead

Comment: Of interest: [“Who wants ice-cream?” — Should I say “(not) I” or “(not) me”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/4556/142322)

Comment: Of interest: [Which is correct, “you and I” or “you and me”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/which-is-correct-you-and-i-or-you-and-me)

Comment: Strangely related: [*Me and you, and you and me /
No matter how they toss the dice, /
it had to be /
The only one for me is you, /
and you for me /
So happy together*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKK0OjueX4A)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at https://dictionaryblog.cambridge.org/2014/04/03/the-top-5-ungrammatical-song-lyrics/, there's an example of an error made in the lyrics of Bad Romance by Lady Gaga:

> Gaga, a serial offender, is guilty of the reverse error in the song
>   ‘Bad Romance’, with this line:
>
> You and me could write a bad romance. Me could write a bad romance? If
>   only she could pay as much attention to her pronouns as she does to
>   her outfits…

*You and me* is not correct in a subject, as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for **"you and I" or "you and me"?** is the same as the answer to: **"I" or "me"?** ...

> I went to the store
>
> He gave it to me.

similarly

> You and I went to the store
>
> He gave it to you and me.