# According to me, it was acceptable, but according to him, it wasn't

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, indirect-objects, italian

I once had a piece of written work corrected by a very experienced English teacher who told me that writing "*according to me*" sounded weird and nobody who was English/British would ever say it. I didn't question him, as there was another teacher, Australian, who nodded her approval and so, blushing I murmured "thanks" and felt terribly awkward and almost ashamed.

I surmised that my "mistake" must have stemmed from my living too many years in Italy. After years of exposure to the Italian equivalent; *secondo me* ("according to" me); *secondo te* (...you); *secondo a lui/lei*, (... him/her); *secondo noi* (...us); and *secondo loro* (...them). "According to me" just sounded natural to my ears.

Fast forward to this summer and what do I discover on EL&U? That my mistake was in fact, *grammatically* correct. [Is the phrase "according to me" correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58560/is-the-phrase-according-to-me-correct)

> [It's certainly grammatical. Whether and where you use it is entirely a
>   matter of personal choice.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/58562/44619)

Another user posted this answer:

> [The use *according to me* is correct, but it doesn't have the same
>   meaning as *in my opinion*.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/58607/44619)
>
> [The form *according to nn* is used when *nn* is some kind of authority, so
>   if you are using it on yourself, you are also implying that you are an
>   authority in the field.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/58607/44619)

I prefer the second answer because it explains why *according to me* sounded odd to the English language teacher. I now no longer make this mistake but after all this time, it still bothers me. Who is to say, that by saying *according to him* the nominated person is an authority. If I say:

> According to my brother, our father will have to go to a nursing home
>   one day.

Would that be technically wrong? "My brother" is not an authority, and he may be younger than I am. If I were to rebuke this claim by saying:

> Well, *according to me* he shouldn't. He would hate losing his freedom
>   and independence.

Would a native English speaker find this phrase *odd* and even [laughable](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58560/is-the-phrase-according-to-me-correct#comment155526_58560)?

Comment: By the way, Mari-Lou, I don't think we would usually find it laughable, no... but maybe just a tiny bit amusing. I can, however, think of using it _intentionally_ in a sort of humorous way, but it's hard for me to illustrate this without actually saying it out loud, sort of in a grandly expressive, self-mocking kind of way. Hey, but that's just _according to me_, you know, and _who would ever listen to me_, right?? (hint, hint, wink, wink)(well, not even remotely a common usage, mind you, but I thought it was worth two cents for fun :)

Comment: "According to me" is a common response when someone asks you "According to whom?"  Slightly weird otherwise, but not "wrong", just not idiomatic.  (Though of course if the Queen says it it's perfectly fine.)

Comment: I've heard "according to [non authority figure]" many times..."According to Ben we were supposed to get a taxi at 16:00."  Ben is my coworker, not an authority.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"According to so-and-so" is a well-accepted phrase to indicate a certain *level* of authority. It doesn't mean *authority* in the sense of *indisputable, world-class, absolute* authority. It means authority only at the level of indicating that this is the person to whom the statement can be attributed.

It therefore has rather wide usage, all the way from *according to my brother, Nancy went to the dance with Frank*, right on up to *according to Einstein, the universe is curved*.

The lowest level of its reference to authority, however, is the second person, *according to you*, which sometimes is used sarcastically, thus: *According to you, I should never have bought stock in Microsoft. Boy, were you wrong*.

We don't take it down to the first person, because that becomes overly emphatic, or to put it another way, redundant. *According to me* is simply saying, *this is what I say*. It isn't considered necessary to say *this is what I say* when you say something. You just say it, don't you? I can tell you *Nancy went to the dance with Frank* without saying *According to me, Nancy went to the dance with Frank*, you see?

If we look at your examples, Mari-Lou, we can see a little bit more of why the usage sounds a bit strange to native English speakers. Since we *do* imbue a bit of authority to the *according to* locution, we usually feel *according to my brother, our father will go to a nursing home someday* does sound odd; we would instead tend to say *my brother thinks our father will go someday*, and the response would be *but I don't think so* rather than *according to me he won't*. *According to* in standard English usage is given some weight of authority, even at the lowest level. It isn't taken as purely opinion.

Comment: I see! I thought *according to* is synonymous with saying; "In my/his/her etc. opinion".

Comment: At http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=199120 is an example of one situation where it wouldn't sound too outlandish: "Say in a heated discussion between A and B - 

A: That is ridiculous.

B: According to whom?

A: According to me!

_It would be an infrequent usage."  And I agree about the moderate level of authority connoted. 'In my / his / their opinion' has a modality connoting rather less conviction in the accuracy of what follows (and tone can adjust the level of endorsement). 'According to me' sounds pompous; J Smith in a scientific article might use 'According to J Smith'.

Comment: I had no idea that saying: *according to me* sounded sarcastic, pompous or "smart alecky".

Comment: *According to the doctors, our father ...* is probably more likely than *according to my brother*, but there is nothing actually wrong with either.

Comment: @bib Agreed; you can give your brother some degree of credibility in his opinion. It's not wrong to say _according to my brother_ in that context, it's just a matter of what you mean by saying it. Just keep in mind that part of the function of the _according to_ phrase is specifically to GRANT some greater or lesser (but, after all, _some_) degree of credibility and/or authority to whomever it is you are talking about.

Comment: I like your above comment almost as much as your answer. Thank you, so much!

Answer (score 2):

You are talking in third person in a passive aggressive way when you say "according to me".  You might as well say Mari-Lou thinks... Which is also grammatically correct but a little weird.  "According to me" should be kept in the closet and used for smart-alecky answers.

Example: "According to me, you should put on your underwear before your pants."

Comment: But I'm British - my pants *are* my underwear! ;-)

Comment: @TrevorD - you could have said "According to me, my pants are my underwear, but I'm British!"

Comment: @RyeBread That doesn't make sense. I might have said: "I'm British and according to OED, pants are underwear."

Comment: @Mari-LouA - it does make sense.  Because I am inferring a smart-alecky tone.  Trevor made a comment about my example in a nice way.  My comment was him doing the same thing but with more of a smart-ass tone.