# "He and I", "Him and me"

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“My friends and I” vs. “My friends and me” vs. “Me and my friends”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/my-friends-and-i-vs-my-friends-and-me-vs-me-and-my-friends)

Somebody taught me a rule of thumb how to discern if I should use "I" or "Me" when adding self to the end of a list of people in a sentence: Ignore the list, strip the rest and treat it only as if it was the singular "me", choose one that matches.

Still, often I see things like *John and me went to the park*. Is this just a common error or are there some specific rules where *I* will be replaced by *me* if appearing on a list?

Comment: It's just a common error. There are some issues between "It is I" and "It's me", but I'm sure that's been covered in a previous question, along with "It is I who am..." and "It is me who is..."

Comment: Come on. This question gets asked almost every week, and has been discussed to death. The first [comprehensive answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/my-friends-and-i-vs-my-friends-and-me-vs-me-and-my-friends/1197#1197) dating back all the way to 2010.

Comment: @RegDwighт: I tried searching but kept coming up with ordering issues (place self at the end of the list) and "I/Me" in singular context (as in Andrew's comment). The accepted answer from your link barely skims the issue and I have to read in into another (not accepted) one to get to the core.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard English requires *I* in subject position, producing *John and I went to the park*. Other dialects, however, allow *me* in subject position when the pronoun is coordinated with a noun or another pronoun.  That is why you will see, or more likely hear, *John and me went to the park*.