# Can you imagine Dad and I putting up with this?

Tags: pronouns, subjects, objects

In the questions "Can you imagine Dad and I putting up with this?" is the subject pronoun 'I' correct, or should it be 'me?'

Comment: Also worth reading: [Angela was reading to Frank and I vs to Frank and me – which is correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200554/angela-was-reading-to-frank-and-i-vs-to-frank-and-me-which-is-correct/200558#200558). ODO and CGEL disagree on whether the former should be considered [ODO] a hypercorrection (and thus by definition incorrect) or, because so many people use it [contrast 'Angela was reading to Frank and they/we/she ...'], standard English [CGEL]. CGEL say the test @sumelic suggests is unreliable.

Comment: I disagree with the notion that usage should be considered *standard* solely *because so many people use it*. I think rather that an awful lot of people are far too content to use (and accept) substandard English. And now I'm reconsidering my decision to get myself a copy of the CGEL.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tendency, especially in unfiltered, spoken English, to treat a construction like *Dad and I* as a single unit without any regard to the case of the pronoun, although the same speaker most likely would use the correct pronoun when used alone. Sometimes it even appears in print. This phenomenon has nothing to do with hypercorrection, i.e. a grammar rule applied in the wrong situation, but following a different grammar, though a non-standard one.

This tendency is so strong that it produces oddities such as this:

[image]

So my advice is to continue declining pronouns according to case until such constructions appear with some frquency in edited works rather than, say, BBC comedy scripts or talk shows.

Comment: Hypercorrection is an interesting topic.  Would you classify: _Please contact Dad and I as soon as possible?_ as a hypercorrection. If not, could you give an example?

Comment: I would consider that as another instance of what I described: a “frozen” noun phrase. To me, a hypercorrection would be someone learning Strunk and White’s absurd rule of never using _which_ in a restrictive relative clause, coming away with a vague notion to use _that_, then using the latter word in a non-restrictive relative clause where it doesn't belong. Wikipedia is full of such constructions. Labelling something a hypercorrection is not a value-free description, but often seems patronizing, assuming, for instance, that they not only misapply the rule, but do so to appear more educated.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it depends on the intention of the speaker. If she has corrected her initial impulse to write _contact Dad and me_ because of some dimly remembered proscription of _and me_ (as in _John and me went to the cinema_), then it could be rightly called a _hypercorrection_. But with hypercorrection, as with many other grammatical terms, grammarians do not agree on what to designate as such.

Comment: My point is that hypercorrection can’t explain both _contact Dad and I_ and _my wife and I’s anniversay_, but the notion of fixed noun phrase and possession as a feature of NPs rather than a case declination of nouns and pronouns does.

Comment: I agree. But I think we're looking at the issue from different perspectives: speaker's reasons for choosing a particular phrase vs. the syntactic features of that phrase.