# Is it correct to say "My partner and I"?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“My friends and I” vs. “My friends and me” vs. “Me and my friends”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/my-friends-and-i-vs-my-friends-and-me-vs-me-and-my-friends)

I'm not sure since sometimes people also say 'My partner and me'