# Which would be correct? Owen and I or Owen and me

Tags: grammar

Caption over picture of Owen and his dad..."Owen and I"   is this correct grammatically ?

Comment: Why not? It's a caption, not a sentence. (Of course, a paternity test might be needed to see if it's **truly** a correct statement.)

Comment: This has been covered many, many times before. See these two most excellent answers: [one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/should-i-put-myself-last-me-and-you-vs-you-and-me/1197#1197), [two](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4556/who-wants-ice-cream/4655#4655), which actually mention labeling photos.

Comment: Ack. The duplicate is itself a duplicate of several others. I feel like I'm in [Fabrege Shampoo](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DmcskckuosxQ&ei=AccoUovGIci92gXA-oGwCg&usg=AFQjCNFpvAIOjLftl3ABYa2wfxbNVNFNMw&sig2=Qde3D9DkWSueXM4om8cc4Q&bvm=bv.51773540,d.b2I) commercial!

Comment: Please never just ask “Which is correct?”  It shows no effort on your part, and gives us nothing to go on.  As [the Help Center says in its “How to ask a good question” section](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):  **“Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!”** Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between "Owen and I" and "Owen and me" is completely dependent on the sentence in which it is found.

If "Owen and I" are the subjects of the sentence (e.g. Owen and I are in this picture), it would be "Owen and I".
If it is a picture of "Owen and me," where "Owen and me" functions as the object, then "me."

The simple test for determining correctness is to simplify the phrase to "me" or "I" (remove "Owen") and look at its correctness.

In the case of a caption, you would need to answer what the full sentence is.

Admittedly, I would rarely have a caption that just said "I", although I would say "I am doing X" in the caption.  If the picture is of "me" and I just wanted to say "me" that is the more logical construction - assuming you are thinking of it in that fashion. Since I hate being the subject of my own pictures (let alone even being in them), I tend towards the implied passive "[This is a picture of ... ] Me"

That said, you really are better off with a full sentence (Owen and I are...) or, better yet, make the caption more third-person (Owen and Rita).

Comment: Good explanation, but I must dismiss the part about being "better off with a full sentence." Who needs a full sentence on a picture caption?? _This is me and Owen on our front lawn. I am pushing Owen on the swing. Owen and I visited a park on Saturday; here we can be seen on a bench._ Yawn. _Owen and me_ is just fine. If a picture is worth a thousand words, there's no need to fill in the details according to strict grammatical rules.