# Usage of Me or I

Tags: personal-pronouns

This is kind of a basic question, but I would appreciate your input. If you're describing a photo of you and a friend, do you write:

```
"My friend and I"
```

or

```
"My friend and me"
```

I understand the usage of "I" as a subject and "me" as an object, but what about the above case where there's no verb?

Comment: See these two excellent answers by an actual linguist: [one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/should-i-put-myself-last-me-and-you-vs-you-and-me/1197#1197), [two](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4556/who-wants-ice-cream/4655#4655). And please search the site before asking in the future, as this question has been asked 30+ times before. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As the caption to a picture (which I assume is the context you mean), either is potentially possible (as is "Me and my friend", which may turn out to be the more common variant of the three). However, in a *formal* article or other type of writing, some authors may prefer the more formal-sounding variant "...and I".

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the verb that's implied. For example, "Here's a photo of my friend and me." In this case, "my friend and me" is the object of the preposition "of", and therefore, you use the direct object form "me". If the two of you are the subject of the sentence, "My friend and I are in a photo we took on vacation.", then you and your friend are both subjects of the sentence (and you are "I", the subject form of the first person).

What I can't stand is the overuse/misuse of "myself" when either "me" or "I" will do and are more correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's no different from when you use it in a sentence: treat it the same way as if you were the only one there.

As a bare pronoun with nothing else you would normally write "me" rather than "I" so with a conjunction you get  "my friend and me".  Conjunctions just don't have an impact on pronoun choice.

That said, a sentence describing what the two of you are doing together is probably a better option.  It's more engaging and more informative.