# Subjective or Objective pronouns in dialogues?

Tags: pronouns

Let's say I'm quoting a dialogue between me and my friend, should I use subjective pronouns (I / He) or objective pronouns (Me / Him)?

For example:

> Me: What's up?
> Him: The sky.

Or:

> I: What's up?
> He: The sky.

Comment: This is a question of style, not grammar, and probably belongs on writing.se rather than here. In my view "Me/Him" is normal, "I/He" is pretentious.

Comment: I agree it's a matter of style with "me" more usual, but you can compare questions about photo captions and other things https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313/when-do-i-use-i-instead-of-me https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4556/who-wants-ice-cream-should-i-say-not-i-or-not-me https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110601/should-a-photograph-label-read-you-and-i-or-you-and-me https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222205/photo-caption-me-or-i

Comment: Use either style.  But be consistent.  Probably don't use *Me* and *He*.