# Which pronoun for a photo caption?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

Which is the correct pronoun, if you have a title for a photo that is, for example “John and me, outside our house”. To my mind that is the correct way to write it but others think it should be “John and I, outside our house”. Or if you just wanted a title for a picture of the two of you it would be “John and me”. But I’ve seen “John and I” as a photo caption in a published book by a well-known writer.

Is he wrong, or is there some reason to use “I” instead of ”me”?

Comment: This is exactly the same question as [Q222205](/q/222205), which is a duplicate of the one specified here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [photo caption ... 'me' or 'I'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222205/photo-caption-me-or-i) {closed as a duplicate of  [Should I put myself last? "me and my friends" vs. "my friends and me" or "my friends and I"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/should-i-put-myself-last-me-and-my-friends-vs-my-friends-and-me-or-my-fri)}

Comment: Just use the names: say "John and Nikey outside our house".