# Is "meet with X and me" (instead of "X and myself") liable to look wrong to stupid administrators?

Tags: personal-pronouns, register

My natural instinct is to write, "X met with M and me in June."  But I've noticed that school officials tend to use "myself" in place of "me" in this type of sentence.

A [related ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/411341/112436) elicited an answer that quoted an article in Collins.  I haven't been able to find it online, and the author didn't record a link, but here's the quote:

> Usage Note: The -self pronouns, such as **myself**, **yourselves**, and **herself**, are sometimes used as emphatic substitutes for personal pronouns, as in *He was an enthusiastic fisherman like myself*. The practice is particularly common in compound phrases: *The boss asked John and myself to give a brief presentation.* Although these usages have been common in the writing of reputable authors for several centuries, they may not sit well with many readers today. A majority of the Usage Panel dislikes them, though resistance has been eroding over the years. In our 1993 survey, 73 percent disapproved of the fisherman example quoted above. In 2009, only 55 percent disapproved of the same sentence. The Panel still finds the use of *-self* pronouns in compound constructions even less appealing, but here too the percentages have fallen over the years. In 1993, the John and myself example was rejected by 88 percent of the Panel. In 2009, 68 percent rejected the same sentence.

I myself don't like "X met with M and myself in June," although I do understand that it's acceptable.  My question is, in a formal letter sent to a school bureaucrat, that I don't know very well yet, is "X met with M and me in June" likely to look wrong in the eyes of an unsophisticated reader?

Comment: It's correct. Stand your ground!

Comment: I completely agree with Kate Bunting, but why has 'met with' replaced 'met' or had a meeting with'? And why has 'speak with' replaced 'speak to'? Less aggressive, I guess. I still say, 'I'd like to speak to you but please don't be frightened.' We're *all* snowflakes now  ;-)