# Is 'me and my friends' possible?

Tags: word-choice

Is it possible to put it like that or is it typical of spoken English only and in written English only 'My friends anf I possible'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I put myself last? "me and my friends" vs. "my friends and me" or "my friends and I"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/should-i-put-myself-last-me-and-my-friends-vs-my-friends-and-me-or-my-fri)

Comment: https://youtu.be/e5hXtGkzZ9k

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if "me" is used as an objective personal pronoun, for instance, like: "Martha gave the money to me and my friends."

Answer (score -2):

"Me and my friends" is not grammatically correct. "Me" is not a subject.

Correct form is like you wrote: "my friends and I".

Comment: Without any additional context how can you be so sure?

Comment: There's a gradual shift in what is held acceptable with questions of case. Pullum, for instance, said long ago something like "If there's a ring at the door and when you ask 'Who is it?' the visitor answers 'It is I,' don't let them in. It's nobody you want to know." // However, it's considered better to close-vote duplicates on ELU than to answer them.