# John, Valencia, and I (or me)?

Tags: word-choice

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Should I Put Myself Last (“me and you” vs “you and me”)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/should-i-put-myself-last-me-and-you-vs-you-and-me)
>   [When do I use “I” instead of “me?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313/when-do-i-use-i-instead-of-me)
>   [Who wants ice-cream?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4556/who-wants-ice-cream)

When identifying people in a photo—for instance,

> John, Valencia, and (I or me).

should I use ”I” or “me”? Which one is grammatically correct?

Comment: See these two most excellent answers: [one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/should-i-put-myself-last-me-and-you-vs-you-and-me/1197#1197), [two](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4556/who-wants-ice-cream/4655#4655), which actually mention labeling photos.

Comment: These folks are all right, but this is a place where grammatically, common usage is totally wrong.  The grammatical response to "Who is that in the picture?" is "That is I."

Answer (score 1):

I would use 'John, Valencia, and me' if I were creating a caption in a photo.  It's such an informal context that you might come off a bit affected if you used I.

Also, the rule with I is that it is used as a subject pronoun in a sentence, and since you are not saying 'John, Valencia, and I go to the beach!' (or something like it), it is better to keep it 'John, Valencia, and me.'

Answer (score 1):

If you would answer "Who is on Valencia's right?" with "Me" (as I would), then your answer to "Who is in the photo? should be "John, Valencia and me".

Answer (score 1):

The accusative is the default in English. If I pointed to you in the picture and said "who is that", you would say "me", not "I". Generally in a non sentence like the photo label, "me" or "us" would be appropriate.

Curiously, if you make it a sentence, "This is John, Valencia and I on vacation" you would use "I" here, but only because you would be using a special verb form, called a copula, meaning the nominative "I" is used as the verb's compliment.

If the caption said "Valencia kissing me on vacation" (or "Valencia punching me on vacation" depending on your relationship with Valencia) you would use the accusative "me".