# Is it "me" or "I" and why?

Tags: pronouns, subjects, syntactic-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do I use “I” instead of “me?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313/when-do-i-use-i-instead-of-me)  
>   [John, Valencia, and I (or me)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25312/john-valencia-and-i-or-me)

I found a photo of Sarah, Thomas, James and I?

OR

I found a photo of Sarah, Thomas, James and me?

"I" subject pronoun,  photo "object",   "me" object pronoun - or not as the case may be?

I believe it is "me" not "I" but can you provide why this is so in terms of sentence structure.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Simple rule: **If** it's the subject of the verb, use ***I***. Otherwise, use ***me***.

In the sentences you provide, *I* is indeed the subject of the verb *found*.

The other pronoun at the end, however, is **not** the subject of a verb, so it should be ***me***.

(Probably this question will get closed because it's too basic, but this **is** the simple answer.)

Comment: No, it will get closed because it gets asked at least once a week. (^_^)