# Should a photograph label read “you and I” or “you and me”?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, grammar, personal-pronouns, grammatical-case

I had a debate with my friend about this topic because he had a photo captioned:

> Seth and I playing lion king

and I said it should be

> Seth and me playing lion king

Which is correct?

Comment: Both are used when it is the subject of a sentence; conventional grammar demands "Seth and I". Although your phrase is not a sentence, an ellipsis where this is the subject of the sentence seems the most reasonable.

Comment: I know it's a similar question but I need an answer for this specific example.

Comment: Definite nTuplicate.

Comment: I have voted to close, but I'll just say that you can use whichever you like. I would write 'Seth and me', because it's less formal.

Comment: More on this [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25312/john-valencia-and-i-or-me), [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/my-friends-and-i-vs-my-friends-and-me-vs-me-and-my-friends) and [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110553/photographic-pronouns).

Comment: @Cerberus In English, we would never label our photos in the nominative;  it just isn’t done.  One labels it “me”, never “I”. Same for the other pronouns. Nohat explains this [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/4655).

Comment: This is only a duplicate of the ice-cream question, not of the other one.

Comment: This is a picture of me: label it *me*.

Comment: @tchrist: In English, traditional grammar recommends "I" for subjects. The status of photo labels is debatable, as I said. I haven't studied your dialect.

Comment: @Cerberus It’s not “my dialect”, so you can drop that now. There is no question of “traditional grammar” either. Read nohat’s answer. The default case in English is the object case.  Native English speaker no more label things “I” than native French speakers label things “je”.  It’s just plain *me*, just like it’s *moi*. In other languages, it works differently, but not here.

Comment: @tchrist: We are clearly talking about different things. English is nothing like French. Read a few style books.

Comment: @Cerberus If you think native English speakers label things with bare subject pronouns instead of bare object pronouns, then you should stop reading style books and get to know some native speakers instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can't really insist on one or the other being correct, because you are not working with a complete sentence. I think the best you can do is to recognize that the majority of English speakers would use "Seth and me."

Even if you add the implied initial phrase that would make it an entire sentence ("This is"), you still wind up with some debate. "This is I" is formally correct (i.e "This is Seth and I playing lion king"), but the vast majority of English speakers consider it pompous and awkward, and still would use "me."

Comment: Your first sentence is best; it depends what you consider the implied words are. 'This is a picture of Seth and I' would be actually wrong ( a classic hypercorrection).

Comment: @TimLymington Exactly. If you consider it that way, "Seth and [somebody]" become indirect objects, and "me" becomes correct.

Comment: I'm not even sure that the 'formally correct' label is warranted nowadays. 'Formerly', perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

It **has** to be “Seth and me playing lion king” as the title of a photo.  Imagine it without Seth there at all: you would always, only, and ever label that photo “Me”, never “I”.  Since the case of a pronoun never changes when you add in somebody else with an *and*, we arrive at “Seth and me playing lion king” as the only right answer.

[We just had a question about this](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/110559), but see also [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/4655) for more about English using the object case not the subject case by default.