# "X and I" versus "Me and X"

Tags: word-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do I use “I” instead of “me?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313/when-do-i-use-i-instead-of-me)

Apparently I use 'Me and xxx' in conversation often enough that a foreign English speaker I work with has started using it as well.  When he said it I automatically corrected him. ;)

Clearly I've picked this up from somewhere.  Does anyone know if it's a regional variation?  I do recall a teacher having a go at someone over saying it when I was at school, but he Wasn't From Round Here...

Comment: It's a common "error", but I've never heard anyone suggest that it's particularly associated with any specific regional dialect. It probably crops up everywhere people speak English.

Comment: Hence the famous song: "My shadow and I"

Comment: Voted to close, 'tis a duplicate.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate question. It asks not "What's the rule?" but "Is there regional variation of those following the rule?"

Comment: @FumbleFingers: this example has been hugely tied up for a long time with questions of formal vs. colloquial, prestige vs. non-prestige use, hyper-correction, etc; it definitely has demographic variation, and I’d be amazed if there isn’t sometimes a strong regional component to that.

Comment: @PLL: I've no idea how one could collect all the relevant data, but it seems likely to me the prevalence of this usage will correlate to a greater or lesser extent with lots of factors. Region, social class, age, education, etc., not to mention spoken/written, and formal/informal contexts *for the same speaker*. I just don't think it would be particularly enlightening, or that we should read much into any regional variation, even supposing we could reliably establish that it exists.

Comment: I'd like to point out that this is not remotely an exact duplicate of the proposed question, which is concerned with copulas and prepositions. And nor is it a duplicate of the more relevant "he and I" style questions. I'm quite aware of the rules surrounding the usage, which the previous questions I found discuss;  quite clear on what is taught to be correct and the theories behind that. I'm asking whether the use is *regional* or not, which the previous questions didn't ask, so while it may overlap there is no way it's an exact duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

Standard English does not allow *me and X* in subject position but it is found in other varieties of the language.

Comment: [Emonds](http://fine.me.uk/emonds) argues that it is found in _all_ naturally learned varieties of English.

Comment: _postition_ or _position_?

Comment: @ColinFine but is Standard English a naturally learned variety of English?

Comment: Can't find the exact reference in that rather long paper, but, on the other hand, ‘[Kim and me saw the accident] will be heard in the speech of speakers of dialects that have a different rule for case inflection of pronouns: they use the accusative forms (me, him, her, us, them) whenever the pronoun is coordinated. Standard English does not.’ (Huddleston and Pullum, ‘Cambridge Grammar of the English Language’)

Comment: I realise that in Huddleston and Pullum's example the coordinated element (Kim) precedes rather than follows 'me', but the grammatical point is the same.

Comment: @morphail: No, Emonds' case is that what he calls "prestige dialect" is not, and cannot be, a naturally learned variety of English.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the -1?

Comment: @ Colin: ‘Roughly speaking, Standard is the kind of English which is:   1. written in published work,  2. spoken in situations where published writing is most influential, especially in education (and especially at University level),  3. SPOKEN “NATIVELY” (AT HOME) BY PEOPLE WHO ARE MOST INFLUENCED BY PUBLISHED WRITING - THE “PROFESSIONAL CLASS” ’ (My emphasis).
 
(Richard Hudson, 2000. Full text here: http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/dick/SEhudson.htm)