# I vs. Me in a book title

Tags: pronouns, subjects

I saw a book for children with the simple title, "Spot and **I**". I believe this should be "Spot and **Me**", since it is not a complete sentence, and both *I* and *Me* are 1st person singular pronouns, which means that they are used by one person to refer to himself or herself. *I* would be the subject pronoun if the words were used in a complete sentence, and *Me* would be the object of the verb, if, for instance, the sentence was, "Spot and I ran through the field". But this is not a sentence, so *I* seems wrong to me. Thoughts?

Comment: Your question may be answered here: ["Who wants ice-cream?" — Should I say "(not) I" or "(not) me"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4556/who-wants-ice-cream-should-i-say-not-i-or-not-me)

Comment: Also relevant: [Should a photograph label read “you and I” or “you and me”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110601), [Why is the accusative case used for a “topic”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67049)

Comment: Also: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/1197/184766

Comment: Since there have been such a quantity of relevant questions and answers, perhaps this question is off-topic because you must provide prior research.

Comment: In the answers to questions, the fragment should take the case that it would if no words were elided ("I [do] [want ice-cream]"), although "me" is acceptable.  In the book title, the fragment is a subject, so "Spot and I [did something]."

Comment: @sumalic For the ice cream it should be "I" because we say "I want icecream" but none of us talk like that! For the photo graph I'd go for "You and me", on the basis that the title is short for "A photograph of you and me"

Comment: In actual spoken use, most people (Americans anyway) would say me even in a sentence.

Comment: As *Spot and I* is not a complete sentence you don't know whether they are jointly the subject of the object. It could be *Spot and I went walking* or it could be *This is a picture of Spot and me*.

Comment: There have been at least three movies called *She* ([1935](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She_(1935_film)), [1965](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She_(1965_film)), and [1982](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She_(1982_film))), at least one of which was based on [a novel of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She:_A_History_of_Adventure).  Do you suggest that they should have been called *Her*?

Comment: @WS2 - the title is telling you that it is a subject rather than an object.  The author could indeed have used the objective case, such as a title like "9/11 and me".

Comment: @Scott Perhaps *herself*!