# Which is correct, I or me?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, personal-pronouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [When do I use “I” instead of “me?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313/when-do-i-use-i-instead-of-me)

Which is correct?

> The photo shows my kids and me at the party.
>
> The photo shows my kids and I at the party

Another one:  Which is correct?

> This is Jean and I at the swimming pool.
>
> This is Jean and me at the swimming pool.

Comment: See these two most excellent answers: [one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/should-i-put-myself-last-me-and-you-vs-you-and-me/1197#1197), [two](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4556/who-wants-ice-cream/4655#4655), which actually mention labeling photos.

Answer (score 3):

If you take out the extra words before "me" in your sentences, you get

> The photo shows me at the party *compared to* The photo shows I at the party.
>   This is I at the swimming pool *compared to* This is me at the swimming pool.

**Me** is correct in both cases, so it's also correct when you add the other words back:

> The photo shows my kids and me at the party.
>   This is Jean and me at the swimming pool.