# When to use I vs me in a sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Which is correct.

Dan thought it would make sense for me and Val to attend training.

OR
Dan thought it would make sense for Val and I to attend training.

Comment: Use _I_ as the subject of a finite (inflected) verb. Otherwise use _me_. In the examples given, _me_ is correct because the infinitive _to attend_ is not a finite, inflected verb. The subject of an infinitive or a gerund or participle is never _I_ (or _he_ or _she_ or _we_ or _they_) but rather _me_ (etc.)

Comment: See also [When do I use “I” instead of “me?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313) and [Should I put myself last? “me and my friends” vs. “my friends and me” or “my friends and I”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1133)

Answer (score -1):

The first one is correct. As the subject is “it” and verb is “would” and I in object always become me. you could alsowanted say “ dan and I though it would make sense for me and Val...

Answer (score -1):

The first sentence is the correct one. You should use the **object** form of self "me" as the **object** of the preposition "for".

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8NniL69fRKM